# Matlab Errors:Too many output arguments

Tags: matlab

Apologizes and thank you for spending time on my question.I am searching for a long time.But it doesn't work.
Here is my simple code to compute integral.I don't know why it's wrong.

```
syms t;
n=11;
t=-50.*pi:0.1:50.*pi;
T=2.*pi;
y=sawtooth(mod(0.5.*t,2.*pi),1);
k=2.*pi./T;
f=y.*exp(-1j.*n.*k.*t);
for n=1:11
    for m=1:length(t)
        sum(n)=sum(n)+1./T.*int(f,[-T./2 T./2]);
    end
end
```

And here is the errors:

sym/subsref
too many output arguments.

int (line 162)
rSym = mupadmex('symobj::intdef',f.s,x.s,a.s,b.s,options);

title_1 (line 12)
sum(n)=sum(n)+1./T.*int(f,[-T./2 T./2]);

Comment: `sum` is a function name. Don’t use it as a variable name. I suspect your code is wrong because of this. Did you initialize `sum` as a variable somewhere? Put `sum = zeros(11,1)` before your loop.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try to correct my code in your way.